# A scary oracle - who am I?

Tags: riddle

Every day, people press me for advice, which I offer honestly. I never lie.
Often, they don't listen.
Sometimes they become scared of me and stop asking my opinion.
But usually they come back in the end. After all, I'm the only reliable source of information on this subject.

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you

> A scale (as in, the type that measures weight)?
>
>  It's not unusual for people to get discouraged when the scale (which, provided it's calibrated correctly, never lies) tells them they're too heavy or too light. There's no other (reasonable, efficient, accurate, etc.) way to find out how much you weigh than by getting onto a scale.

Comment: Great answer, except for the last sentence.  Some evidence to the contrary: [1](http://www.livestrong.com/article/273055-how-to-calculate-your-weight-without-a-scale/) [2](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Weight-of-an-Object-Without-a-Scale) [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fk1OjYxZz0w)

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain lol

Answer (score 9):

This may be a bit abstract, but I'd like to think you are AN (oh no, that's practically a spoiler!)

> Alarm clock.

Every day, people press me for advice, which I offer honestly. I never lie.

> Many people have to get up at specific times every day, and they press their alarm clocks to tell them when to get up.  The alarm clock can only respond with the same level of accuracy that it was given.

Often, they don't listen.

> Some people sleep through their alarms, when the volume is too low or if they are too deep in sleep.  Others simply ignore the alarm, wanting to sleep in a little later and snooze.

Sometimes they become scared of me and stop asking my opinion.

> Many people dread having to wake up in the morning to the ringing of their alarm, counting in their heads the hours of precious sleep they still might capture.  Some end up just trusting their bodies to wake up at the appropriate time, while others just throw their cares by the wayside.

But usually they come back in the end. After all, I'm the only reliable source of information on this subject.

> Even if one goes without the use of an alarm clock, say to sleep in on vacation or on the weekend, they will return to using it when they have to, because it is a reliable tool in telling them how many hours have passed and one that tells them it's time to get up.

Answer (score 7):

You are

> A mirror

Every day, people press me for advice,

> "Does my hair look decent?  Do I need a shave?"

which I offer honestly. I never lie.

> The mirror shows your reflection as you are.

Often, they don't listen.

> "I'm not really losing my hair, it's just my imagination."

Sometimes they become scared of me and stop asking my opinion.

> "Screw you, I'm not gaining weight, it's just water retention."

But usually they come back in the end.

> You can't avoid your reflection forever.

After all, I'm the only reliable source of information on this subject.

> I mean, you could take a photograph, but photos can be doctored, go out of date, etc.  Your reflection in the mirror is always accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Are you:

> "Nutrition facts" information on food bought in supermarkets. Or any food nutrition labels in McDonalds etc.

Comment: Hi! I added spoiler markup to your answer, but you might want to consider adding a little more to flesh out this answer for reasoning.

Comment: Aah, an interesting answer...

Answer (score 1):

You are

> Google

because

> People press the buttons and search for your advice. You show search results, well accurate(honest) as per the search keywords and page-rank algorithm. You don't lie. And yes, often people don't listen as they think that these search results are irrelevant.
>
>  People are scared of you, as you contain their emails, search history, location and what not... Sometimes, people stop asking your opinion and use other search engines like Bing :-P
>
>  But they come back, as you are reliable source of information on (almost) anything.

Comment: is it the ONLY reliable source for this information?

Comment: @LN6595 Yes, that is the reason I'm still skeptical about the correctness of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are:

> A person's conscience.  You are the only place to find out whether a person feels something is right or wrong. People are often afraid of finding out if they feel what they're doing is wrong, because doing what they feel is right could cause them adverse effects.

Alternately you could be:

> A person's heart. In terms of old school metaphors, the heart tells you what you truly desire.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Can you give more details? One-sentence answers are almost always deleted; we want to see why you think this could be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are:

> The Brain

Every day, people press me for advice, which I offer honestly. I never lie.

> You think objectively, and you will just get meaningful and realistic ideas yourself. In your depth, you always know the truth.

Often, they don't listen.

> But you still refuse the listen! You are trying to avoid your thoughts and try to follow your heart (strong reference to relationships,etc)

Sometimes they become scared of me and stop asking my opinion.

> Brain is scumbag, so sometimes it may lead you doing stupid mistakes including CRIME or SUICIDE! This is the time you should stop thinking.

But usually they come back in the end. After all, I'm the only reliable source of information on this subject.

> Ih the end, brain is all you've got. It is your sanity, it is you. You can only trust yourself.

Comment: I don't know - brains lie all the time.  False memories, delusions of self-importance, imagined patterns in randomness, etc.  There's a reason single-person eye-witness testimony is considered one of the weakest forms of evidence in courts.